# Not sure why REG ADD command line does not run in VS setup post build event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, registry, vsto, windows-installer, post-build-event

In the post-build Event, I have had the following command line,

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\General /v EnableLocalMachineVSTO /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

, which adds a DWORD type value under the registry key `General`.

I don't know what else I am missing here - the command line `REG ADD` just doesn't seem to work for me. After the installation, that key is still missing. If I run it alone using  Command Prompt, it's all good though.

Comment: Ensure that you run VS elevated when you do this on Vista or higher so you'll have write access to HKLM.  Right-click the shortcut, "Run as administrator".

Comment: Thanks, Hans. That seems to be a permission issue. Also, another question here, will the installer ignore post-build event if there's an error there?

Comment: @woodykiddy, what was the actual solution? If running VS elevated solved it, can you accept the answer?

Comment: What tool are you using to make the installer?

Comment: Never mind, didn't realize this was an ancient question - showed up as new because someone edited it.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with visual studio build events.
Even with admin privilege, it cannot register in HKLM. 
instead if u try with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, it works great.

```
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\General /v EnableLocalMachineVSTO /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```